# Troubles with java generics and linked lists/ques

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I am currently running into problems with java generics, linked list/ques structures and methods that should operate on them. Currently, I am trying to write generic methods that should manipulate a linked list of jobs for my school project. I have to implement basic methods, such as enque, de-que, sort-by-priority, get number of elements and so on. The element is, say, a printing job with a priority. A print que shall be implemented as a linked list of jobs. I am not allowed to use any pre-defined collection classes.

This being said, I am not getting something obvious. In the java code shown below, there are 3 classes (Job, MyPrintQue and LinkNode) and one generic interface (PrintQue). I am not importing any other classes from java.util. In the line 85 I use a curr.data.getPriority() method, but curr.data is taken here as the type Object, instead of the type Job, and therefore does have getPriority() method defined. Not sure why is that and how to fix it.

I've gone through a couple of related posts here, but have not found any remedy to my problem. Would be grateful for any input.

Here's the code:

Class Job

```
public class Job {  

private int priority;  

public Job(int i) {this.priority=i;}  

public int getPriority(){return priority;}  
public String toString () {return String.format("This job has priority %d", priority);}  
  }
```

Class MyPrintQue

```
public class ListNode<Job> {  

    public Job head;  
    public ListNode<Job> tail;  

    ListNode (Job j) {this.head=j;}  

    public Job getHead(){return head;}  
    public void setHead(Job j){}  
}
```

Interface PrintQue

```
    public interface PrintQue<Job> {  

    public void enque(Job j);  
    public void deque(ListNode<Job> n);  
    public void printQue();  
    public boolean isEmpty();  
    public ListNode<Job> hasTheHighestPriority();  
    public void sortByPriority();  

}
```

and Class MyPrintQue

```
    public class MyPrintQue<Job> implements PrintQue<Job>  
{  
    //Setting up front and end elements of a print que.  
    private ListNode<Job> front;  
    private ListNode<Job> end;  
    private static int queLength;  

    //Accessors for head and tail.  
    public ListNode<Job> getFront(){return front;}  
    public ListNode<Job> getEnd(){return end;}  

    public void enque(Job j)   
    {  
        if (front == null && end  == null)   
            {  
            front = new ListNode<Job>(j);  
            queLength++;  
            }  

        else if (front !=null & end == null)  
            {  
            end = new ListNode<Job>(j);  
            front.tail =end;  
            queLength++;  
            }  
        else   
            {  
        ListNode<Job> temp = new ListNode<Job>(j);  
        end.tail = temp;  
        end = temp;  
        queLength++;  
            }  
    }  

    public boolean find(ListNode<Job> n)  
    {  
        for (ListNode<Job> curr = front; curr !=null; curr = curr.tail)  
        {  
            if (curr == n) return true;   
        }  
        return false;  
    }  

    public void deque(ListNode<Job> n)  
    {  
        if (find(n))  
        {  
        for (ListNode<Job> curr = front; curr !=null; curr = curr.tail)  
        {  
            if (front == n) {front = n.tail;}  
            else if (curr.tail == n) {curr.tail=n.tail;}      
        }  
        n = null;   
        queLength--;  
        }  
    }  

    public void printQue()  
    {  
        int length=0;   
        for (ListNode<Job> curr = front; curr !=null; curr = curr.tail)  
        {  
            System.out.println(curr.head);  
            length++;  
        }     
        System.out.println(length);  
    }  

    public boolean isEmpty(){if (front == null) return true; else return false;}  

    public ListNode<Job> hasTheHighestPriority()   
    {  
        ListNode<Job> temp = new ListNode<Job>(null);  
        int prior = 0;  

        for (ListNode<Job> curr = front; curr.head !=null; curr = curr.tail)  
        {             
            if (prior <= ((curr.head).getPriority()))   
            {  
                System.out.printf("Current priority is %d, top priority is %d%n", curr.head.getPriority(), prior);  
                temp = curr;  
                prior = (int)curr.head.getPriority();  
            }         
        }     
        return temp;  
    }  

    public void sortByPriority()  
    {  
        MyPrintQue<Job> temp =  new MyPrintQue<Job>();  

        while(!isEmpty())  
        {  
            temp.enque(hasTheHighestPriority().head);  
            deque(hasTheHighestPriority());  

        }  
        front = temp.front;  
    }     
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need generics in your case? I don't, but if so, you should not use the same name for the generic type and the Job class (ex: declare "public class ListNode<J>")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your

```
public class MyPrintQue<Job> implements PrintQue<Job>
```

and

```
public class MyJobPrintQue implements PrintQue<Job>
```

is that in the first case Job is a generic type parameter, nothing to do with the class Job.
And the rewrite, there is a PrintQue of the class Job.

Instead of parameters `<Job>` better use `<J>` or whatever.

For good order "queue" is the spelling in English (for an explanation "few" also has double u).

---

The NullPointerException can be removed by:

```
if (front == n) {
    front = n.tail;
} else {  
    for (ListNode<Job> curr = front; curr !=null; curr = curr.tail) {  
        if (curr.tail == n) {
            curr.tail = n.tail;
            break;
        }      
    } 
}
```